# Dropdownlist selected default value after canceled confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRh16.jpg) My dropdownlist loaded this:
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.field, new { @class = "form-control select", type = "text", id = "dropdownlist" })

```
Javascript:
$("#dropdownlist").on("change",function () {
            var asdf= document.getElementById("#dropdownlist");
            swal({...},function (isConfirm) {
                  if (isConfirm) {
//post url
}
else{
if isconfirm false I want to dropdown list selected default value
how ı can
}
```

Comment: default value you mean the first `<option>` of the dropdown ?

Comment: yes the first <option> value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    $("#dropdownlist").on("change",function () {
            var asdf= document.getElementById("#dropdownlist");
            swal({...},function (isConfirm) {
                  if (isConfirm) {
    //post url
    }
    else{
        $("#dropdownlist option:first").attr('selected','selected');  //this will do the job for you.
    }
```

Comment: @alettin, how this has helped you.

Comment: not working.else{ alert("warning");
        $("#dropdownlist option:first").attr('selected','selected');  //this will do the job for you.
    } alert worked but code not working

Comment: actually ı want selected value <option> before new selecting value

Comment: I did not understand this _actually ı want selected value <option> before new selecting value_

Comment: I checked the same jquery code for my dropdown and it worked well. So if you can see alert then this line should work.

Comment: after canceled the option value the first but dropdownlist display new selecting

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. Can you give me example please ?

Comment: ı added example img. the first screenshot pageLoad, the secand select admin. the last when ı cancelled "admin" dropdownlist show admin. ı want to show "callcenter"

Comment: I can write this : window.location.href =url/id; I do not want to reload the page

Comment: @alettin, thank you for accepting my answer. Can you up vote it ?

Comment: My reputation less than 15 :(